# Why my bash-script doesn't work with cron?

Tags: command-line, server, bash, scripts, cron

I created a bash script to automatically update my Ubuntu Server. 
Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
echo "Update am $(date "+%d. %m. %y|%H:%M:%S) >> /var/log/update.log
exit 0
```

The log file is always empty.
crontab:

```
0 3 * * * /drives/files/scripts/update.sh
```

I know, that I can set, that the Ubuntu Server update automatically in the settings, but this is to learn about cron and a little bit scripting.

Thanks

Comment: What does not work with your script? Does it not run or what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you are using crontab with normal user which means that he can't update/upgrade a system without providing a sudo.

Also `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` will prompt user for confirmation so you have to pass this confirmation before.

```
yes | apt-get update
yes | apt-get upgrade
```

So to solve it you have to run your commands with sudo, but this will put you in problem how to provide the password to the sudo.

Moreover

```
echo  "Update am "$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") >> /var/log/update.log
```

is writing in /var/log/... which means need permission to do that which is not founded for a normal user.

In order to solve that you should run your script in the root cron.

```
sudo crontab -e
```

will open the root cron file in your default editor.

Add the entry of your script

```
0 3 * * * /drives/files/scripts/update.sh
```

Now save and exit.

**PS**: just in case, be sure that you give execution permission for your script. to do that run the command:

```
chmod +x /path-to-script
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for this fast answer.
First: I use sudo. I open the crontab with sudo. But I think I know the problem. I forgot the "yes". I will correct it and then report.

Comment: @ssd_rider you are welcome

Comment: And I noticed too, that the script wasn't executable. Thanks.
Is there a chance to test the cron, without to wait to the start time of the job? Like an testparm from samba?

Comment: you can find your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8132355/test-run-cron-entry

Comment: I didn't test the cron but i manuelly tested the script and I noticed, that the script also don't work perfectly. Now it have to work. I will wait to tomorrow.

Comment: Yes, but the timestamp wasn't correct. Now it works perfectly:
`echo "Update am "$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") >> /var/log/update.log`

Comment: @ssd_rider Welcome

Answer (score 0):

**Why its not working ?**

To do `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` you must become a sudo user. I mean your script should executed with sudo privileges.

**Any other stoppings ?**

Yes , you are not doing giving `-y` that let upgrade command automatically download after update.

**Is it a major thing ?**

Yes , if you dont pass -y along with command then your cron will stop and looks for '-y' arguement and it wont execute till it get '-y'

**How to execute cron script as root user ?**

```
sudo crontab -e
```

It will ask you choose editor and choose nano then there add your line.
But complete script should be this

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade -y
apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Why -ve vote ? It means my answer wrong or too good ?

Comment: Same thing happens to me and don't know what matters with people who downvote